# Eclipse 4 based GEF editor

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef

Currently, I am creating Eclipse 4 based RCP application which has parts (view and editor). 
I want to add a GEF-based graphical editor. But didn't find any tutorial for Eclipse 4 and GEF.

Currently, I saw GEF4 too but its rendering engine is Javafx. Don't I should use GEF4 as I have to provide drag and drop feature between graphical editor and different parts.

Any tutorial link or suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks
Shashwat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this link which has details about GEF4 https://github.com/eclipse/gef/wiki/MVC. But still wondering if its supports drag and drop of object to different parts and GEF4 editor.

Comment: Drag and drop can be implemented as a DragDropGesture. We did this for a customer, and it was no big deal. You are tied to JavaFX for the visualization, but you can still access SWT. You can register for a free GEF tutorial here: https://info.itemis.com/en/gef/tutorials/  However, that tutorial does not cover E4 or drag'n'drop.